# Iterate over single row in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm isolating a subset from a dataframe, and trying to convert the headers into values.  Here is the subset I'm working with

[image: single row dataframe with headers reading out a series of mVs].

I'm trying to convert the headers back into data, and remove the mV tag, but when I convert the header back into a row, Pandas isn't letting me iterate over it.  How can I remove the "mV_" text and convert the values into floats?  Here's what I've tried so far.

```
def scatterer(df):
    df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
    df=df.drop(['Wavelength'], axis=1)
    df = df.columns.to_frame().T.append(df, ignore_index=True)
    df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
    print(df.head(1))
    for i in df.head(1):
        i=i.replace("mV_", "")
        i=float(i)]
```

This gives the error

> "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your solution:-

write this code outside of `function`:-

```
df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
df=df.drop(['Wavelength'], axis=1)
df = df.columns.to_frame().T.append(df, ignore_index=True)
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
```

Now just use `apply()` method:-

```
df.loc[0]=df.loc[0].apply(lambda x:x.replace('mV_',''))
```

Now Just use `astype()` method to convert them to `float`

```
df.loc[0].astype(float)
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your desired output